# $httpBackend respond undefined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, httpbackend

Trying to get a similar behavior as in [Example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)

*UnitTest.coffee*:

```
describe 'Unit: EditAccessController', ->
  ...
  (var $httpBackend, personRequestHandler)   
  personUrl = /\/people\/\d+/
  testPerson = { personId: 123 }
  ...
  beforeEach inject ($injector) ->
    ...
    # Set up the mock http service responses
    $httpBackend = $injector.get '$httpBackend'

    personRequestHandler = $httpBackend.whenGET(personUrl).respond(testPerson)
    console.log(personRequestHandler)  # undefined
    ...

  it 'should ....', ->
    personRequestHandler.respond(404, { errors: [{ message: 'Person not found' }] })
    ...
```

Somehow `respond()` not returns `reguestHandler` and  turns *Can not read property 'respond' of undefined'*. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That example is from the docs for version 1.3, which version are you using? You might want the 1.2 branch... https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/docs/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Comment: You are right, i use `"angular": "1.2.x"`, thanks!